# Replace multiple fields/columns in one files with contents from another file if the headers are the same

Tags: csv, unix, awk, replace

I have two CSV files that share similar headers:`sample_scv_1.csv` is::

```
Transaction_date,Name,Payment_Type,Product
1/2/09 6:17,NA,Mastercard,NA
1/2/09 4:53,NA,Visa,NA
1/2/09 13:08,Nick,Mastercard,NA
1/3/09 14:44,Larry,Visa,Goods
1/4/09 12:56,Tina,Visa,Services
1/4/09 13:19,Harry,Visa,Goods
```

Similarly, `sample_scv_2.csv` is ::

```
Transaction_date,Product,Name
1/2/09 6:17,Goods,Janis
1/2/09 4:53,Services,Nicola
1/2/09 13:08,Materials,Asuman
```

Here in these two files Columns/Fields `Transaction_date`, `Product`, `Name` are common and I want to replace fields `Product`, `Name`  in `sample_scv_1.csv` iff the transaction date matches in both the files.

This is a toy example and my file is big. For this example I can separate the cases where columns are equal and use indices to replace using  csvtool as:

```
head -4 sample_scv_1.csv > temp1.csv
tail -3 sample_scv_1.csv > temp1_1.csv
#sudo apt-get install csvtool
csvtool pastecol 2,4 3,2 temp1.csv sample_scv_2.csv > temp1_2.txt
cat temp1_2.txt temp1_1.csv > sample_scv_1.csv
```

My required output is ::

```
Transaction_date,Name,Payment_Type,Product
1/2/09 6:17,Janis,Mastercard,Goods
1/2/09 4:53,Nicola,Visa,Services
1/2/09 13:08,Asuman,Mastercard,Materials
1/3/09 14:44,Larry,Visa,Goods
1/4/09 12:56,Tina,Visa,Services
1/4/09 13:19,Harry,Visa,Goods
```

I can determine until which line the transaction date matches but I can not know the indexes where the two columns overlap: like Name and Product in first file. One issue is easy as all columns of `sample_scv_2.csv` will be in `sample_scv_1.csv`. Any ways to do this efficiently.

Comment: Please let us know [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/). Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got from the attempt you made to solve this yourself, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: _[your] file is [are?] big_ How big?

Comment: @ghoti : Thanks. However, I have shown an example of what I have tried with the csvtool above. I haven't mentioned others for brevity.

Comment: @JamesBrown : My data has around 350 columns and 500k rows.

Comment: Both files are the same size?

Comment: @JamesBrown: The number of columns are not. I can however make the number of rows equal by using `head` and `tail`. All the columns in  `sample_scv_2.csv` appear in `sample_scv_1.csv` but not viceversa

Comment: Your question is tagged *[tag:awk]*, but you have included no awk code in your question. That says to me that either (1) you have not written any awk code but recognize that it should be possible and are asking for a handout, or (2) you wrote something that didn't work, and didn't realize that THAT was the attempt you should have included with your question, rather than csvtool. I'm hoping for the latter, but I suspect the former. Let's see the awk code you're having trouble with, and we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the files are not bigger than that the file with less columns or fields fits in the memory, so a solution in awk:

```
$ cat program.awk
BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}         # set the file separators
NR==FNR {                  # for the first file
    p[$1]=$2               # store the product, use date as key
    n[$1]=$3               # name
    next                   # no more processing for the first file
} 
$1 in p {                  # if date found in first processed file
    if($2=="NA") $2=n[$1]  # replace NA with name
    if($4=="NA") $4=p[$1]  # replace NA with product
} 1                        # print the record
```

Run it:

```
awk -f program.awk file2 file1
Transaction_date,Name,Payment_Type,Product
1/2/09 6:17 Janis Mastercard Goods
1/2/09 4:53 Nicola Visa Services
1/2/09 13:08 Nick Mastercard Materials
1/3/09 14:44,Larry,Visa,Goods
1/4/09 12:56,Tina,Visa,Services
1/4/09 13:19,Harry,Visa,Goods
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to replace everything not only cases where there are NAs. Plus, the solution assumes we know the indexes where we need replacements but that is little difficult in file with 350 columns. Can it be generalized?

Comment: You can store every value from `file2` to memory and use that to replace fields in `file1`. You need to know the indexes to match the records. I mostly use awk, magic not so often. There has to be something to compare.